# Old version of a script is imported using import on Python

Tags: python

I am currently trying to load function from another .py file. I have in the same folder: algo.py and test_algo.py. I need to import all functions from algo in test_algo so I use the command:

`from algo import *`

The import is succesful however one function `do_sthg()` takes 3 arguments in algo but the imported version requires 4 arguments which was the case in a very old version of the code. I deleted all .py~ related files and there are not any other scripts with the name algo on my computer. How is that possible and how can i solve this issue?

(I can not specify the full links to my script as it should change over time, I am using 2.7 version of Python)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some example code that causes this?

Comment: Can you share the traceback..

Comment: Try `import algo`, then `print algo`, it should print the name of file from which the module was loaded. `import sys` then `print sys.path` in in serious doubt. Also, `rm *.pyc` just in case.

Comment: Just ran those commands still have the same issue. I can not really share an example as i'd have to upload my scripts and i am not allowed to. Will keep you updated if I find a solution. Edit: the path to my file was not printed as it should have.

Comment: do you really need to import `*`? It might be caused because what you imported has an import to another package containing the same `do_sthg` function. Either you grep through your files or import what you need only (which works the best most of the time)

Comment: When I just import the functions I need I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have not been able to determine where the problem was so I just specificied the full path using the command getcwd from os. It has worked so far. It means I must have a hidden .pyc or .py~ file somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should always import files within their own namespace. You should use

```
import algo 
import test_algo as algoT 

print(algo.do_sthg(p1, p2, p3))
print(algoT.do_sthg())
```

That way you will be able to segregate the results from different files. Also, if you are using iPython, you need to `exit()` and start it again.